# watch is not triggered when empty the ref object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have created a dynamic model for filtering in vue 3 and have some problem when clear (empty the object)

```
 setup() {
    const model = ref({});

    watch(model.value, (value) => {
      console.log("model changed");
      console.log(model.value);
    });

    const addLanguage = (language) => {
      model.value["meta_" + language.toLowerCase()] = language;
    };

    const clear = () => {
      model.value = {};
    };

    return {
      addLanguage,
      clear,
    };
  },
```

I have also created a sample here for test https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-chebyshev-9tjogk?file=/src/App.vue

Adding new element to the model... the watcher is triggered .... but when you clear the object (empty) the watch function is no more triggered.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The watch source (i.e., `model.value`) gets replaced in `clear()` with an empty object, so the watcher no longer gets triggered.

#### Solution

1. Instead of unwrapping the `model` ref, pass the `ref` itself as the watch source.
2. Pass the `deep` flag to the watch so that property addition/deletion is observed.

```js
watch(
  model, 1️⃣
  (value) => { /* handle change */ },
  { deep: true } 2️⃣
)
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/deep-watch-on-object-35r7no?file=/src/App.vue)